# Wrap_Content in a grid-shaped RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on displaying a simple 9x9 game board using a RelativeLayout.
Each EditText in the board has a custom XML shape in the background, which provides the square's color and border.

The XML is much too large to put here, so here's a link:

pastebin.com/LPDs5MLM

Right now, I'm using hard-coded values for the board and square sizes. This isn't ideal, so I'd like to switch to something scalable. With the board and square sizes hard-coded, my board looks like this:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiVQG.png)

This is the output I'm looking for. However, when I use "wrap_content" for the board size instead of a hardcoded value, I get this output:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHDBp.png)

Here's a quick summary of how the RelativeLayout is set up.
The middle square (middle row and column) is defined as:

```
        <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:text="M"
        android:id="@+id/textview44"
        android:background="@drawable/square"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/square_size"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/square_size"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

The squares to the left of the middle square are positioned to the left.
Each square is positioned to the left or right of the square before it. 
This is repeated for all 9 rows.

```
        <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/textview43"
        android:background="@drawable/square"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/square_size"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/square_size"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textview44"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
```

Clearly, something is wrong with the way I made the RelativeLayout. Is there any way to fix this?
Apologies if this is an easy fix, I'm very new to Android development.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead? Then create a custom adapter and custom layout with EditText for each cell. This way, you only have to set one size in one cell or let the GridView automatically set the sizes equally.